# Phonegap App lost images on update, recovering from the camera roll

Tags: iphone, cordova, uri

I have an app where users take images and they are saved along with user notes. Per the following link this is what I was using to save the images to the app. The issues is when some users update the app the images are lost.

[Phonegap - Retrieve photo from Camera Roll via path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180731/phonegap-retrieve-photo-from-camera-roll-via-path)

per the bosses instructions the users aren't allowed to browse the gallery for images as they are being used as proof of work performed (small company, 5-12 employees using the app).

is there any way for iphone to relay back to the app the actuall image location on the camera roll like android does? Then I can just save the URI to the database and call it when the form is submitted...

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, the images must be saved the the app itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI()

to convert the filelocation to a fileentry or else your filepath will contain the App UUID which changes when you update/deploy your app.